# How to play with a json object in the same file where it needs to be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was a doing an AJAX call:

```
var getHoursOfOperation = function() {
    $.ajax('hours-of-operation.json')
        .done(function(data, status, xhr){
            now = window.moment(xhr.getResponseHeader('Date')).utc().format();
            hours = data.hours;
            holidays = data.holidays;
            refTimezone = data.timezone;
            // console.log(now, hours, holidays);

            console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Date'));

            // process date against hours and holidays
            checkIfOpen(now);
            applyChatStatus(currentStatus);
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log('there was a problem loading hours-of-operation.json');
            // applyChatStatus(currentStatus); // there was an error, go with default state?
        });
};
```

but now I need to include the data of this file `hours-of-operation.json` in the same file where I am doing that call, like this:

```
var dataJSON = {
   "timezone":"America/New_York",
   "hours":[
      {
         "day":"Sunday",
         "open":"0000",
         "close":"0000"
      },
      {
         "day":"Monday",
         "open":"0800",
         "close":"2200"
      },
      {
         "day":"Tuesday",
         "open":"0800",
         "close":"2200"
      },
      {
         "day":"Wednesday",
         "open":"0800",
         "close":"2200"
      },
      {
         "day":"Thursday",
         "open":"0800",
         "close":"2200"
      },
      {
         "day":"Friday",
         "open":"0800",
         "close":"2200"
      },
      {
         "day":"Saturday",
         "open":"0000",
         "close":"0000"
      }
   ],
   "holidays":[
      "2015-01-01",
      "2015-01-19",
      "2015-02-16",
      "2015-05-25",
      "2015-07-04",
      "2015-09-07",
      "2015-10-12",
      "2015-11-11",
      "2015-11-26",
      "2015-12-25",
      "2016-01-01",
      "2016-01-18",
      "2016-02-15",
      "2016-05-30",
      "2016-07-04",
      "2016-09-05",
      "2016-10-10",
      "2016-11-11",
      "2016-11-24",
      "2016-12-25"
   ]
};
```

so I guess this line `$.ajax('hours-of-operation.json')` should change to this `$.ajax(dataJSON)` where as you can see `dataJSON` is the variable containing the whole data that I need to complete the AJAX call.

The issue I have is that the 'data' parameter now is returning the index.html. Look the code first:

```
var getHoursOfOperation = function() {
    $.ajax(dataJSON)
        .done(function(data, status, xhr){
            console.log('___data___', data);                
        })
};
```

that `console.log('___data___', data)` returns this:

[image]

so, can you tell me what the difference? I mean one call is from an external `json` file, and the other is exactly the same but the data is in the same file where I am doing the call. So, what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't get this: are you trying to load data from a file on the web server, and save modified/updated data on the same file via ajax?

Comment: No no, @loretoparisi, all I need is to obtain with the variable `dataJSON` the same result that I was getting when I was doing the AJAX call.

Comment: @loretoparisi, as long as I know, if I have the data in the same file, I don't need an AJAX call, but, how can I use that data in the variable `dataJSON` in order to obtain the same result that I was getting when I was doing the AJAX call?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer: The same way you use any other variable.  What don't you understand?

Comment: `var getHoursOfOperation = function() { var hours = dataJSON.hours; /*...*/ };`.

Comment: there is no need to use `ajax` then here.

Comment: Need to understand that because it has a variable declaration...that is not valid json. It is javascript. You could also access the variable using `getScript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a local variable in your file, you can use it directly.

You don't need AJAX of any kind.

Comment: can you tell me then how to use that data in the function `getHoursOfOperation` in order to get the same result like when I was doing the AJAX call ?

Comment: Just use your variable.

Comment: How do I simulate this part: `now = window.moment(xhr.getResponseHeader('Date')).utc().format();` ?

Comment: I mean, what do I put instead of `xhr` if `xhr` was a param before.

Comment: You don't.  You don't have an AJAX response.

Comment: Thats what I don't get. Because I need to use `now` variable. For example: `now = window.moment(xhr.getResponseHeader('Date')).utc().format();` and I need to use it here: `checkIfOpen(now);`

Comment: Then you do need an AJAX request, and your question doesn't start.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer: You can get the current local time using `Date.now()` (if that's what this code is doing). I guess the question, what exactly are you using `xhr.getResponseHeader('Date')` for?

Comment: Do you understand what AJAX _is_? And what your code means?